# Go Regexp to Match Characters Between

Tags: regex, go

I have content I am trying to remove from a string

```
s:=`Hello! <something>My friend</something>this is some <b>content</b>.`
```

I want to be able to replace `<b>content</b>` and `<something>My friend</something>` so that the string is then

```
`Hello! this is some .`
```

So basically, I want to be able to remove anything between `<.*>`

But the problem is that the regex matches `<something>My friend</something> this is some <b>content</b>` because golang is matching the first `<` to the very last `>`

Comment: I've never used it, but https://github.com/PuerkitoBio/goquery is supposed to be useful for navigating HTML content like this.

Answer (score 4):

`*` is a [**greedy**](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-greed.html) operator meaning it will match as much as it can and still allow the remainder of the regular expression to match. In this case, I would suggest using negated character classes since backreferences are not supported.

```
s := "Hello! <something>My friend</something>this is some <b>content</b>."
re := regexp.MustCompile("<[^/]*/[^>]*>")
fmt.Println(re.ReplaceAllString(s, ""))
```

[<kbd>**Go Playground**</kbd>](http://play.golang.org/p/ghZzkZpNGD)

Answer (score 2):

Go's regexp doesn't have backtracking so you can't use `<(.*?)>.*?</\1>` like you would do in perl.

However if you don't care if the closing tag matches you can use:

```
<.*?/.*?>
```

Just saw your update, `.*` is a greedy operator, it will match everything in between, you have to use non-greedy matching (aka `.*?`).

<kbd>[play](http://play.golang.org/p/KPfHIG4HNK)</kbd>